# (ConTeXt MkIV) Text in PiechartMP

Tags: context-mkiv, graphs, metapost, charts

So I need to include some pie charts in my document. As I'm using Metapost for all graphics I tried using the `PiechartMP` Metapost package. But for some strange reason no text shows up, just a very tiny square.

The minimal example:

```
\startMPinitializations
input piechartmp ;
\stopMPinitializations

\startreusableMPgraphic{pie}
u := 5mm;
r := 3u;
SetupPercent(this, "x") ;

Segment(32.5,"first",auto);
Segment(12.8,"second",auto);
Segment(22.4,"third",auto);
Segment(18.2,"fourth",auto);

beginfig(1);
PieChart(r, 0, 0, 0, 0);
SetupValue("{\tfd ", "}");
label (btex textext(Text) etex,origin);
endfig;
\stopreusableMPgraphic

\starttext
\reuseMPgraphic{pie}
\stoptext
```

I've tried with `TEX` (loading the Metapost `TEX` module), with `\sometxt` and `textext` commands without success. Setting a bigger or different font in Metapost just makes that square bigger, but it shows no text. Am I doing something wrong? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I looked into it but do not have a solution. PiechartMP assumes that you will be using latex or tex to typeset the logos. The obvious solution was to replace `_makeText` to `textext` in piechartmp.mp, but that did not work. The piechartmp code is too complicated to debug.

Comment: Hmmm I see... So better I look for another solution for doing those piecharts, maybe tikz?

Comment: Or look for another chart (seriously, pie charts are a very bad way of representing information http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Pie-Charts-Are-Bad/

Answer (score 10):

#### The fix (short version)

You are missing the plain compatibility mode:

```
\starttext
  \startMPcode
    useplainlabels ;
    input piechartmp;
    Segment(30, "first");
    Segment(70, "second");
    PieChart(1cm, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    Label.auto(0)(name)(outwards,0);
    ResetSegments;
  \stopMPcode
\stoptext
```

[image: screenshot1]

#### Reason for the failure

In contrast to traditional MetaPost, MkIV uses mplib, the MetaPost
library built into LuaTeX. In mplib many MetaPost variables have
been placed into a
[`namespace`](http://tinyurl.com/pnegy5k)
to separate the internal code and reduce the chance of name clashes.
Usually this is no problem, users rarely alter them directly. A few MetaPost modules however, among
those the PiechartMP module, rely on the original names and are thus
incompatible with LuaTeX. Newer modules should use the MetaPost
[`installlabel`](http://tinyurl.com/qds8py3)
macro to define label directions in a portable way.

The key problem here is that PiechartMP defines the custom label
direction `auto` using the traditional names and mplib then
attempts to typeset those labels using the offsets the function
[`thelabel`](http://tinyurl.com/nrbw236) calculates,
which assumes the namespaced new names.

To make PiechartMP modules work with mplib you need the plain
compatibility mode. This mode is included in ConTeXt since
*2013.08.25 14:06*. To switch to  compatibility mode, use the macro
[`useplainlabels`](http://tinyurl.com/ovygdul) or the corresponding environment version:

```
startplaincompatibility ;
  … some MetaPost code …
stoplaincompatibility ;
```

#### Workaround for older ConTeXt versions

Since the plain compatibility mode has been included rather recently and you cannot update your installation for some reason you might need a workaround. The simplest one would be to overwrite the label printing function to use the traditional names that PiechartMP uses. The drawbacks are that you can expect manually typeset labels to break.

```
\startMPinclusions
    input piechartmp;

    vardef thelabel@#(expr p,z) =
        if string p :
          thelabel@#(rawtextext("\definedfont[" & defaultfont & "]" & p)
            scaled defaultscale,z)
        else :
          p shifted (z + labeloffset*laboff@# - (labxf@#*lrcorner p + labyf@#*ulcorner p + (1-labxf@#-labyf@#)*llcorner p))
    enddef;
\stopMPinclusions

\starttext
  \startMPcode
    Segment(30, "first");
    Segment(70, "second");
    PieChart(1cm, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    Label.auto(0)(name)(outwards,0);
    ResetSegments;
  \stopMPcode
\stoptext
```

#### Improve label typesetting

You attempted to adjust the fonts within the pie chart. Such
adjustments are best done in the MetaPost instance, which should be
created for those graphs. The advantage is that the code is
separated and does not interfere with other MetaPost code.
Additionally, the MetaPost instance can be customized using
[`\defineMPinstance`](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/defineMPinstance)

Another improvement is to couple the MetaPost labels with ConTeXt
and make them adapt to the body font. By default MetaPost draws
the labels using the `defaultfont`. This is done by hooking the macro
`textext` into the routing that prints the labels:

```
vardef _makeText primary s =
  textext(s)
enddef;
```

Here an example:

```
\defineMPinstance
  [piechartmp] [metafun]
  [textstyle=bigbodyfont]

\setupbodyfont [pagella]

\startMPinclusions{piechartmp}
  useplainlabels;
  input piechartmp;

  vardef _makeText primary s =
    textext(s)
  enddef;
\stopMPinclusions

\starttext

  \startMPcode{piechartmp}
    SetupPercent(this, "\%");

    Segment(38, "first",  auto);
    Segment(22, "second", auto);
    Segment(22, "third" , auto);
    Segment(18, "fourth", auto);

    PieChart(3cm, 1, 0, 0, .05);
    Label.auto(0)(percent)(inwards,(1,1)) withcolor white;
    Label.auto(0)(name)(outwards,0);
    ResetSegments;
  \stopMPcode

\stoptext
```

[image: screenshot2]

The labels are printed in a larger font because
`bigbodyfont` is used for this instance, and they are printed in
TeXGyre Pagella and adapt to the body font.

And I replaced `MPinitializations` with
[`MPinclusions`](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/startMPinclusions).
The reason for that is that MetaPost initializations are *global* and
not local to a particular MetaPost instance. Furthermore, MetaPost
initializations are [triggered at every
graphic](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.context/80822),
which would execute the definitions more often than necessary.

#### Resetting the segments

Before or after each chart the segments need to be reset using
`ResetSegments`. If the segments are not being reset, they interfere
with the next graphic and too many segments will be drawn. This can
be done manually, which is repetitive and error prone, so it's
better to automate it. As mentioned in the previous section we
figured that MetaPost initializations are being triggered at *every
graphic*. That's exactly what we want here. So let's automatically
reset the segments:

```
\startMPinitializations
  ResetSegments;
\stopMPinitializations
```

#### Three dimensional graphs

By default PiechartMP uses a uniform colour for three dimensional
charts. MetaFun supports shading using the `linear_shade`
macro. Fortunately PiechartMP supports this and can draw more
realistic charts when MetaFun is available. Unfortunately PiechartMP
checks for the existence of the old MkII variable `context_spec`
from the special extensions code which is not included in a recent MkIV, thence it fails. The correct way is to check for
`metafunversion`. Consider this to be a bug in PiechartMP. To fix
this, either define `context_spec` *before* loading `piechartmp.mp` or
set `pc_Metafun` to `true`, which works at *any* point. Here are two
three dimensional graphs, one with the default rendering and one
with MetaPost's linear shading.

```
\setupbodyfont [pagella, 16pt]

\startuseMPgraphic{pie-default}
  input piechartmp;
  Segment(28); Segment(28);
  Segment(32); Segment(12);
  PieChart(3cm, 1, 65, 0, .0);
  ResetSegments;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\startuseMPgraphic{pie-metafun}
  pc_Metafun := true;
  \includeMPgraphic{pie-default}
\stopuseMPgraphic

\starttext

  \startcombination
    \startcontent \useMPgraphic{pie-default} \stopcontent
    \startcaption Default shading            \stopcaption
    \startcontent \useMPgraphic{pie-metafun} \stopcontent
    \startcaption MetaFun shading            \stopcaption
  \stopcombination
\stoptext
```

[image: screenshot]

#### Additional notes

> beginfig(1);
>   …
>   endfig;

Don't use `beginfig(1) … endfig` within an MPgraphic. The figure is
already defined with
[`\startuseMPgraphic`](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/MetaPost_in_ConTeXt#.5CstartuseMPgraphic_and_.5CuseMPgraphic)
or
[`\startreusableMPgraphic`](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/MetaPost_in_ConTeXt#.5CstartreusableMPgraphic_and_.5CreuseMPgraphic).

> SetupValue("{\tfd ", "}");

Set up the text using the `textstyle` key of the MetaPost instance
or redefine `defaultfont` if you don't want to use a dedicated
instance:

```
defaultfont := "Sans sa 1.2";
```

> label (btex textext(Text) etex,origin);

Don't place `textext(…)` between `btex…etex`. Pick one of

```
draw textext("Foo");  %% draws using the body font
label("Foo", origin); %% draws using defaultfont
```

#### Example

Now let's put this all together and create a full example with all
the mentioned features.

```
\defineMPinstance
  [piechartmp] [metafun]
  [textstyle=bigbodyfont]

\setupbodyfont [pagella]

\startMPinclusions{piechartmp}
  useplainlabels;
  input piechartmp;
  pc_Metafun := true;

  vardef _makeText primary s =
    textext(s)
  enddef;

  SetupPercent(this, "\%");
\stopMPinclusions

\startMPinitializations
  ResetSegments;
\stopMPinitializations

\startuseMPgraphic{piechartmp::pie-segments}
  Segment(28, "first"); Segment(28, "second");
  Segment(32, "third"); Segment(12, "fourth");
\stopuseMPgraphic

\startuseMPgraphic{piechartmp::pie-one}
  \includeMPgraphic{piechartmp::pie-segments}
  PieChart(3cm, 1, 70, 0, 0);
\stopuseMPgraphic

\startuseMPgraphic{piechartmp::pie-two}
  \includeMPgraphic{piechartmp::pie-segments}
  PieChart(3cm, 1, 50, 0, .2);
  Label.auto(0)(percent)(inwards,(1,1)) withcolor white;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\startuseMPgraphic{piechartmp::pie-three}
  \includeMPgraphic{piechartmp::pie-segments}
  PieChart(3cm, 1, 0, 0, .1);
  Label.auto(0)(percent)(inwards,(0,1)) withcolor white;
  Label.auto(0)(name)(outwards,0);
\stopuseMPgraphic

\startuseMPgraphic{piechartmp::pie-four}
  \includeMPgraphic{piechartmp::pie-segments}
  PieChart(3cm, 1, 60, 0, .2);
\stopuseMPgraphic

\starttext
  \startcombination
    {\useMPgraphic{piechartmp::pie-one}}   {\useMPgraphic{piechartmp::pie-two}}
    {\useMPgraphic{piechartmp::pie-three}} {\useMPgraphic{piechartmp::pie-four}}
  \stopcombination
\stoptext
```

[image: screenshot4]

#### Final thoughts

Please consider that pie charts are a really bad way of representing
data visually and you should avoid them if possible, particularly
the three dimensional ones. I'll just provide some links here.

- [The Worst Chart In The World](http://www.businessinsider.com/pie-charts-are-the-worst-2013-6)
- [Pie Charts Are Bad](http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Pie-Charts-Are-Bad/)
- [Peltier Loves Pie](http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/peltier-loves-pie/)