# Using sans as a default font in ConTeXt Metapost

Tags: context, metapost, metafun

When using metapost in ConTeXt, I would like to have all my labels in sans by default. Which option can configure it and which environment should I use to pass it (`MPinclusions`?)

I am aware of [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93922/context-mkiv-text-in-piechartmp/130399#130399) but did not fully understand how to implement it (I am compiling with lmtx at home and mkiv at school).

```
\setuppapersize [S3]
\setupbodyfont[sans]


\startreusableMPgraphic{Label}
label ("Typeset in \METAFUN\ ",origin);
% this is what I do know, making the code less readable
% and error-prone, waisting also my time…
% label ("{\ss Typeset in \METAFUN\ }",origin);
\stopreusableMPgraphic

\starttext

Typeset by \CONTEXT\

\blank[big]
\reuseMPgraphic{Label}

\stoptext
```

[image: output: sans in ConTeXt, serif in METAPOST]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works both with LMTX and MkIV:

```
\setuppapersize[S3]
%%% From meta-ini.mkxl
\definefontsynonym[MetafunDefault][Sans*default]

%%% Already set. You can choose another font as default.
%\startMPinitializations 
%defaultfont:="\truefontname{MetafunDefault}";
%\stopMPinitializations

\startreusableMPgraphic{Label}
label ("Typeset in \METAFUN\ ",origin);
\stopreusableMPgraphic

\starttext
Typeset by \CONTEXT

\blank[big]
\reuseMPgraphic{Label}

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. For the record, I digged into ConTeXt font documentation, and found that if I want to change also default metapost font size (for example 11pt in a 12pt ConTeXt document), I should do something like `\definefontsynonym[MetafunDefault][Sans*default at 11pt]`

Answer (score 2):

One could also use `textext` around your string.

In the example below I also added the `\setupbodyfont` inside the `\startMPenvironment` and `\stopMPenvironment`, since it allows for a completely different setup than what is in your main document.

```
\setupbodyfont[termes,ss,12pt]

\startMPenvironment
\setupbodyfont[termes,ss,8pt]
\stopMPenvironment


\startreusableMPgraphic{Label}
label (textext("Typeset in \METAFUN\ "),origin);
\stopreusableMPgraphic

\startTEXpage[offset=3bp]

Typeset by \CONTEXT\

\blank[big]
\reuseMPgraphic{Label}

\stopTEXpage
```

[image: a lot of sans serif text]